# RPI as server for home automation

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, arduino, home-automation

I would like to ask for an advice in choosing controller/platform for my project. Basically what I want to do is RPI local server with web server, where I can display data from arduino sensors and from web page (web server) I need to be able send values to arduino (like temperature... arduino will manage everything else). The connection should be serial (usb) as I don't want to use any shields.

Do you have some recommendation of controller/platform? Is there some simple tutorial for this case?

I tried to use Home Assistant, but in the end I couldn't pass data from web to arduino. Second one, which I tried was Blynk... but I couldn't even connect the arduino to the RPI...

Do you have any advice on these? [PIdome](https://www.mysensors.org/controller/pidome), [myController](https://www.mysensors.org/controller/mycontroller), [myHouse](https://sourceforge.net/projects/my-house/), [Ago Control](https://www.agocontrol.com/documentation/).

I'm using Arduino MEGA and RP-3

Comment: You forgot OpenHAB

Comment: `I couldn't pass data from web to arduino` - so how can you pass data to arduino?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, I didn't explain my problem correctly. It should be better now. Do you think that OpenHAB can handle this communication?

Comment: Why do you want to connect your devices to the RPI via USB/Serial? Why not pass data from the arduino sensors using MQTT or similar?

Comment: @jaolstad I don't want to buy additional shields for arduino. USB is the simplest and easiest connection to make or do you have some advice in using different interface?

Comment: I mean, how do you plan on passing data "from web to arduino" - do you have any thoughts on how you want this to happen? because it's a very vague concept

Comment: @JaromandaX I will have on webpage input, where user set some numeric value (temperature). That will be send to Arduino as it is and Arduino will manage everything else. I hoped that some platform could help me with this... something as firmata.. or .. i dunno

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look on [Domoticz](https://domoticz.com) which provide support for a lot of interfaces

To collect data from remote sensors, in place of arduino you can have a look on [ESPeasy](https://letscontrolit.com/wiki/index.php/ESPEasy) which is free. It is based on an ESP8266 which is very cheap and connects to Wifi (see Wemos modules on ebay). It supports a lot of sensors and can use https or mqtt messages to domoticz or to others

BR